# Values of FULL OUTER JOIN appearing in 2 different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

here is my query:

```
SELECT
COALESCE ([dbo].[RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$].TOS,
[dbo].[RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$].TOS,[dbo].[RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$].TOS,
[dbo].[RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$].TOS) AS [TOS Value]

,RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$.Percentage            AS [Birmingham]
,RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$.Percentage          AS [Cardiff Regus]
,[dbo].[RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$].Percentage    AS [Castlemead]
,[dbo].[RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$].Percentage    AS [Chelmsford]

FROM [dbo].[RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$] 
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$] 
ON [dbo].[RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$].TOS = [dbo].[RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$].TOS

FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$] 
ON [dbo].[RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$].TOS = [dbo].[RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$].TOS

FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$] 
ON [dbo].[RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$].TOS = [dbo].[RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$].TOS
```

And here is the output:

```
TOS Value        Birmingham   Cardiff Regus   Castlemead    Chelmsford
default (DSCP 0)   61.37%       61.74%         99.48%         79.78%
af11 (DSCP 10)     15.22%       4.63%          0.00%          6.16%
af33 (DSCP 30)     11.49%       15.44%         NULL           7.33%
af31 (DSCP 26)     8.86%        13.85%         0.01%          5.59%
ef (DSCP 46)       1.91%        3.72%          0.49%          0.91%
af41 (DSCP 34)     0.70%        0.03%          0.01%          0.05%
cs4 (DSCP 32)      0.15%        0.20%          NULL           0.10%
af12 (DSCP 12)     0.12%        NULL           NULL           NULL
cs3 (DSCP 24)      0.06%        0.11%          0.01%          0.04%
af21 (DSCP 18)     0.05%        0.05%          0.00%          0.02%
cs6 (DSCP 48)      NULL         0.23%          NULL           NULL
cs6 (DSCP 48)      NULL         NULL           0.00%          NULL
af32 (DSCP 28)     NULL         NULL           NULL           0.02%
```

If you have a look at the TOS column and look at value cs6 (DSCP 48) you will see that it has been duplicated.
there should be only 1 cs6 (DSCP 48) row but for some reason the Castlemead value (0.00%) for cs6 (DSCP 48) has been created as a separate column.

there should be only one row per TOS value if that makes sense so please tell where did I go wrong?

Comment: That is values is repeated in one of join table.  And that would be a lot more readable with aliases.

Comment: @Paparazzi what i want to do is get rid of the repeated values.. that was stated on my question.

Comment: But values are not repeated.  Those rows are different.

Comment: Did any of the answers fit your needs? Could you leave a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you get are as expected. This is because the joins are all relative to the first table. If there is a TOS in the second table that has no match with the first table that will generate a  new record. If there is a TOS in the third table that has no match with the first table that will again generate a new record. There is no clue for the engine to know that such instances should be combined 
into one result.

There are probably several ways to resolve this. I will suggest one where you introduce a `UNION` sub select that will combine all TOS values, and then an `INNER JOIN` to each of the four tables.

```
SELECT       REF.TOS AS [TOS Value]
            ,RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$.Percentage    AS [Birmingham]
            ,RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$.Percentage  AS [Cardiff Regus]
            ,RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$.Percentage    AS [Castlemead]
            ,RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$.Percentage    AS [Chelmsford]

FROM       ( SELECT TOS FROM RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$   UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$ UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$   UNION
             SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$
           ) AS REF
INNER JOIN RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$   ON REF.TOS = RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$.TOS
INNER JOIN RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$ ON REF.TOS = RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$.TOS
INNER JOIN RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$   ON REF.TOS = RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$.TOS
INNER JOIN RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$   ON REF.TOS = RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$.TOS
```

Comment: Hi @trincot your query does what i want it to do but i have a few fiels missing from the TOS table: TOS Value
     af12 (DSCP 12)
     af32 (DSCP 28)
     af33 (DSCP 30)
     cs4 (DSCP 32)
     cs6 (DSCP 48)

Comment: Hi Mate, i found a way to get the results that i wanted thanks to your initial answer! instead of using INNER JOIN i replaced it with a FULL OUTER JOIN and that lists all the fields from the TOS table as expected. what i was missing was to use a UNION as you mentioned so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Queries are so much easier to write and to read with table aliases.  The problem is the matching in the second `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  The `FROM` clause needs to look like this:

```
FROM [dbo].[RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$] b FULL OUTER JOIN
     [dbo].[RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$] cr
     ON b.TOS = cr.TOS FULL OUTER JOIN
     [dbo].[RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$] cm
     ON cm.TOS IN (b.TOS, cr.TOS) FULL OUTER JOIN
     [dbo].[RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$] cf
     ON cf.TOS IN (b.TOS, cr.TOS, cm.TOS)
```

In other words, by comparing to only one `TOS` field in the later joins, you might be joining to an unmatched column -- and hence getting a duplicate.  One `FULL OUTER JOIN` is fine.  Multiple `FULL OUTER JOIN`s are tricky.  I often use `UNION ALL` queries instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i get a whole list of new errors when i run the query. i am new to SQL Querying so it could be just me not undestanding the answer propperly. however the answer that trincot gave has produced the results that i wanted so thanks for your help anyway1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @trincot as he is the one who layed the fondation to the outcome that i was looking for. here is the query that has solved my issue:

```
SELECT       REF.TOS AS [TOS Value]
        ,RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$.Percentage    AS [Birmingham]
        ,RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$.Percentage  AS [Cardiff Regus]
        ,RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$.Percentage    AS [Castlemead]
        ,RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$.Percentage    AS [Chelmsford]

 FROM    
         (SELECT TOS FROM RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$   UNION
         SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$ UNION
         SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$   UNION
         SELECT TOS FROM RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$) AS REF

       FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$   ON REF.TOS =  
       RSA_BIRMINGHAM_1941$.TOS
       FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$ ON REF.TOS =
       RSA_CARDIFFREGUS_2911$.TOS
       FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$   ON REF.TOS = 
       RSA_CASTLEMEAD_1941$.TOS
       FULL OUTER JOIN RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$   ON REF.TOS = 
       RSA_CHELMSFORD_1941$.TOS

       ORDER BY [TOS Value]
```

and the result is the following as expected:

```
TOS Value      Birmingham   CardiffRegus    Castlemead  Chelmsford
af11 (DSCP 10)  15.22%      4.63%           0.00%        6.16%
af12 (DSCP 12)  0.12%       NULL            NULL         NULL
af21 (DSCP 18)  0.05%       0.05%           0.00%        0.02%
af31 (DSCP 26)  8.86%       13.85%          0.01%        5.59%
af32 (DSCP 28)  NULL        NULL            NULL         0.02%
af33 (DSCP 30)  11.49%      15.44%          NULL         7.33%
af41 (DSCP 34)  0.70%       0.03%           0.01%        0.05%
cs3 (DSCP 24)   0.06%       0.11%           0.01%        0.04%
cs4 (DSCP 32)   0.15%       0.20%           NULL         0.10%
cs6 (DSCP 48)   NULL        0.23%           0.00%        NULL
defau(DSCP 0)   61.37%      61.74%          99.48%       79.78%
ef (DSCP 46)    1.91%       3.72%           0.49%        0.91%
```